# how to set clickable button at ListView with Navigator.push in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview, kotlin, dart

i set a listView with multiple container, next each container included in StatelessWidget. but finally i have been unable to add clickable button at ListView with Navigator.push. this source code of listView

```
child: ListView(

        children: <Widget>[

          home_left_container("Alphabet", "asset/drink_images/tea.png", Colors.white),

          SizedBox(height: 20),

          home_right_container("Number", "asset/drink_images/juice.png", Colors.white),
          SizedBox(height: 20),

          home_left_container("Word", "asset/drink_images/tea.png", Colors.white),
          SizedBox(height: 20),

          home_right_container("Fun & Sentence", "asset/drink_images/juice.png", Colors.white),
          SizedBox(height: 20),

        ],
      ),
```

Comment: If you want an ```onPressed or onTap``` function. Wrap your Widget ```home_left_container``` with GestureDetector or InkWell Widget class

Comment: @Reign which function will be best to use here

Comment: @Reign i am a new in flutter. can you come in more details please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a button press on your list items, you could wrap those items in `GestureDetector` or some buttons (for example `ElevatedButton`). The simplest approach would be the GestureDetector.

Assuming you want your containers clickable, something like the following would be enough,

```
child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, [define-your-route-here]);
            },
            child: home_left_container("Alphabet", "asset/drink_images/tea.png", Colors.white),,
          ),
          ...

        ],
      ),
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but Back button doesn't appear on navigator in next screen. please help

Comment: In order for back arrow to automatically appear, you need to create an AppBar (without a leading widget) inside a Scafold in the next page. Anyway, you should ask it in anther thread with full source code.